# Bullet pattern isn't behaving as expected

Tags: xna

I have a boss that's supposed to continuously shoot five streams of bullets, each at a different angle. It starts off just fine, but doesn't seem to want to use its entire array of bullets. No matter how large I set the length of bulletList, the boss simply stops shooting after a couple of seconds, then pick up again shortly. Here's what I'm using to generate the pattern:

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0.5f, -1, 0);

for (int r = 0; r < boss.gun.bulletList.Length; r++)
{
   if (!boss.gun.bulletList[r].isActive)
   {
      boss.gun.bulletList[r].direction = direction;
      boss.gun.bulletList[r].speed = boss.gun.BulletSpeedAdjustment;
      boss.gun.bulletList[r].position = boss.position;
      boss.gun.bulletList[r].isActive = true;
      break;
   }

}
direction = new Vector3(-0.5f, -1, 0);
//Repeat with four similar for loops, to place a bullet in each direction
```

It doesn't seem to matter if the bulletList length is 1000 or 100000. What could be the issue here?

EDIT: This is the code that removes a bullet, when it goes out of bounds. It is inside Bullet.Update()

```
if (position.X > 950 ||
position.X < -950 ||
position.Y > 570 ||
position.Y < -570)
isActive = false;
```

This is the code that removes a bullet on contact with the player ship:

```
for (int i = 0; i < boss.gun.bulletList.Length; i++)
{
   if (boss.gun.bulletList[i].isActive)
   {
      boss.gun.bulletList[i].Update(timeDelta);

      if (!ship.invincible)
      {
         bulletSphere.Center = boss.gun.bulletList[i].position;
         if (bulletSphere.Intersects(shipSphere))
         {
             boss.gun.bulletList[i].isActive = false;
             ship.health -= boss.gun.damage;
         }
      }
    }
}
```

And just for safe measure, here's the code that draws the bullets:

```
for (int j = 0; j < boss.gun.bulletList.Length; j++)
{
   if (boss.gun.bulletList[j].isActive)
   {
      Matrix bulletTransform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(boss.gun.bulletList[j].position);
      DrawModel(boss.gun.bulletModel, bulletTransform, boss.gun.bulletTransforms);
   }
}
```

**EDIT: It would appear that a large number of bullets are getting "stuck" on the boss. That is, they draw at boss.position, and never move.**

Comment: What is the interval after which the boss is shooting bullets?
And why don't you use dynamic list?

Comment: The interval is currently TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1). I'm not using a dynamic list because I'm worried that list operations might be too expensive.

Comment: NVM see answer.

Comment: Rather than repeat with four similar for loops you should have an outer for loop which goes through the possible directions (either stored in an iterable of some kind or using basic arithmetic to rotate by 90 degrees).

Comment: Is there a reason why you are breaking out of your loop as soon as you find an inactive bullet?  Wouldn't you want to loop through the bullets and find all inactive ones and re-activate them?

Comment: @Cypher I thought the same but i think he needs just one inactive bullet for that direction. He needs to take out the forloops. It's already a bad design from this little piece of code.

Comment: `Even if I set the size to 10000, it never gets past 500.` Can you post the code that creates and destroys bullets, including the methods that activate/inactivate.

Comment: Additional requested code posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make sure that your bullet are inactive at some point again. Or else your loop won't work. If all bullets are "active" the forloop won't shoot any bullets.

Coupled with break; it will just jump out of your for loop. ( I guess this is meant for the interval ? )

( But then again, I have the feeling you are leaving out some crucial code )

I suggest using a [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) or [ObjectPool](http://blog.gallusgames.com/programming/lean-mean-object-pool-in-c) that just pops the top element and returns an inactive bullet. Once a bullet goes inactive ( after being activated) it's pushed back on the stack. This way you don't need to loop trough your bullet list to see if any of the bullets are inactive. You just check if something is in the stack. It's much faster.

C# has its own [stack class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx) But creating one for your own needs isn't hard.

As an addition you could wrap your bullet patterns into a class which holds the direction for each bullet, the interval time( perhaps per bullet), speed(perhaps per bullet) etc. And when it's time to shoot the next bullet you simply request the next bullet settings from your "BulletPattern" class. This might prevent you writing giant pieces of codes just for one object. If you wrap the data you can also reuse/share them for/with other entities and such.

Comment: The bullets do go inactive, upon either colliding with something or going outside the visible area. However, I'll give it a try with a stack. Arrays have been fine for me up to this point, since this is the most bullets I've ever pumped out.

Comment: Have you tried putting a simple trace/print in your forloop? To see if it actually reaches those lines of code?

Comment: Yes, I have. The strange thing is that it seems to not reach higher numbers in the for loop. Even if I set the size to 10000, it never gets past 500. Furthermore, it will continue counting while -not- firing.

Comment: @Fibericon Then your problem lies elsewhere. Your submitted code isn't sufficient enough to tell us anything. The code seem fine, but I seriously suggest you implement a Stack to retrieve an inactive bullet. Your current design is bloated.

Comment: `Even if I set the size to 10000, it never gets past 500.` Sounds like you have some kind of limiting effect somewhere.  Try toggling `Game.IsFixedTimestep`.  Does that cap change?

Comment: A struct didn't work for me, since I need to be able to modify the bullet's position and isActive members. Setting IsFixedTimeStep to false didn't seem to make any difference at all. However, I just noticed that it seems to be drawing at least one bullet stationary on top of the boss. Edit with more code incoming.

Comment: @Fibericon if you are refering to me, I said Stack.Not struct. Stack is a datastructure. With a stack you can even get rid of the isActive for your logic. A stack is a simple array where you push items on top, to add, and pop the top item to retrieve it.

Comment: I meant "stack", but I seem to be unable to edit and correct that mistake. If it's unnecessary to modify items while they remain in the stack, then I'm confused as to exactly how I would be implementing it.

Comment: Once I figured out to just store the array index in the stack, my problem went away. Seems like the issue really was with the for loop!

Comment: @Fibericon I'm not sure what you mean by "unnecessary to modify items". If you mean the "get rid of the isActive"; The stack simply stores bullets that are in active. The stack represents inactive bullets, so the "isActive" property becomes redundant. But looking at your code you should also try to update alle bullets at a central point. You rather want the ship to call an object that creates bullets for you and adds it to the gameworld. (1/2)

Comment: You specifically assigned your bullets to a certain entity. This could make things more complex than they need to be. If you have one central point where bullets are updated and checked for collision and what not, you wouldn't have to worry about bullet management per shooting object. Manage your game objects in one logical place(each system respectively)(2/2)

Glad it worked out for you.